# Why are exec and proc_open running under different user on IIS?

Tags: php, iis, exec, proc-open

I'm running my site on Windows Server 2012 R2 and IIS 8.5 and I encountered a problem.

- When I run `exec('whoami')`, it returns `nt authority\iusr`.
- When I run `proc_open('whoami', $desc, $pipes)`, the result is `iis apppool\mysite`.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

that is interesting.  It must have to do with the nature of proc_open.  Somehow its going to the share iis pool which has different permissions than the standard user used on IIS.  proc_open has you might already know requests a greater level of control and php under windows is probably needing additional permissions to get that.